# Saved query using filters DFP Ad Units (Top Level) but not compatible with DFP API

Tags: google-dfp

I'm using PHP code and DFP API version v201911.

I create report queries in the Ad Manager UI, and retrieve them with the ReportService.getSavedQueriesByStatement method, but i received the error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The saved query is not compatible with this API version.'

If i delete filter option: DFP Ad Units (Top Level) from the saved query (in the picture) and run file PHP, i received a good result.

Please let's me know what wrong?

Thanks for your support!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8uNx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when i was trying to use a saved query with key-values filtering and then i ran into [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-doubleclick-for-publishers-api/0hCoepBrGEs)
in other words, a lot of the options in the UI are not supported via saved queries but google are not clear about what is allowed.

I hope that saves you some time:)